# #Stata remove rows before event

Tags: stata

I have a unbelanced panel data and have hard time to analyze it 
I would like to remove all rows that I have for each person before an event happens because I'm interested in the effect of the event on other variables 
 
One problem are the many missing values, mostly every other year, the second problem are persons where the "event" occurs more than once, in this care I'm only interessted in the last event as you can see for person 3 in my picture

[image]

Comment: You seem to be showing a worksheet from a spreadsheet, which is a puzzling way to explain Stata data. Use `dataex` -- which is distributed with Stata 15.1 up or otherwise downloadable using `ssc inst dataex` -- to give us an example that can be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are interested in is identifying the last non-missing event, this should do the trick:

```
clear

* Input data
input float id str7 event
1 "1"      
1 "missing"
1 "1"      
1 "missing"
1 "0"      
1 "missing"
2 "missing"
2 "0"      
2 "missing"
2 "missing"
2 "1"      
2 "missing"
2 "0"      
3 "missing"
3 "0"      
3 "1"      
3 "0"      
3 "missing"
3 "1"      
3 "0"      
end

* Re-structure event variable to byte and preserve sort order
replace event = "." if event == "missing"
destring event, replace
gen sortorder = _n

* Identify last event iff event == 1
bysort id event (sortorder): gen lastevent = _n == _N if event == 1
```

I assume you have a time variable to preserve sort order better, but this should serve in the example. Once you have them identified, you can do with them what you wish. Use `keep if lastevent == 1` to drop all necessary observations, or keep them around as missing (for event == missing | 0).